# Using an existing Java class as a type in XSD

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to defines a type in xsd that uses an existing Java class as an extension base ?

My base class has a few functions that have business logic in them. I would like my auto-generated beans to also have those functions. The only way I can think of is to have the types in my XSD extend this base class.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: I've retagged your question `[jaxb]`, since I assume that's what you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Inheritance Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin) from [JAXB2 Basics](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Home) to achieve this.